# How to set value of required attribute in Autowired annotation from application properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

I want to set required value from application properties _ENABLE_COMPONENT_A=false

```
 @Autowired(required = ENABLE_COMPONENT_A)
 private A a;
```

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Please read this [Guidline on how to format your posts](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help&ved=2ahUKEwiD6f6SxY3yAhUcM1kFHTECBwEQFjAAegQICxAC&sqi=2&usg=AOvVaw0PBl56thdOqK1i1SE4URiG)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a property variable, you should use:

> @Value("${ENABLE_COMPONENT_A}")

instead of

> @Autowired(required = ENABLE_COMPONENT_A)

Comment: As I see, we don't want to set the value of the property but the value of the required property in Autowired annotation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you are looking for a feature flag to determine whether a feature/component should be enabled or not. There are many ways to implement feature flags in spring boot. I would propose to use a ConditionalOnProperty annotation if you want to switch on/off your features using properties.

If you are not looking for a feature flag, please explain your use case on why do you want to inject a property within the autowired annotation.

Example https://github.com/faskan/spring-boot-feature-flag

```
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "features", name = "message-service", havingValue = "true")
    public MessageService messageService(){
        return new MessageService();
    }
}

@RestController
class MyRestController {
    private MessageService messageService;

    public MyRestController(Optional<MessageService> optionalMessageService) {
        optionalMessageService.ifPresent(service -> this.messageService = service);
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return messageService.getMessage();
    }
}

class MessageService {

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am using @ConditionalOnProperty on the class A level. But this class A is autowired in class B. This is leaving dependency unsatisfied in class B. Any suggestions pls.

Comment: Check this out. [link](https://github.com/faskan/spring-boot-feature-flag). I have used constructor injection here but you can achieve the same using field injection as well by making the required attribute false.